# EntityFramework VS SQL Stored PROCEDURE

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a table with more than 10,000,000 Rows.

I need some filters (some `in` queries and some `like` queries) and dynamic order by

I wondered what is the best way to work with big data, Pagination, Filtering and ordering.

Of course its easy to work with entity framework, But I think the performance better on stored procedure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table with more than 10,000,000 Rows.

You have a small table, nearly tiny, small enough to have no problems for anyone now abusing the server.

Seriously.

> I wondered what is the best way to work with big data,

That starts with HAVING big data. That is generally defined a smultiple times RMA of a low cost server. Which today has around 16 cores and around 128gbm memory. After that it gets expensive.

General rules are:

- DO NOT PAGE. Paging at the start is easy, but gtting to the end results is slow - either you precalculate the pages and store them OR you ahve to reexecute queries just to throw away results. It works nice on page 1-2, then it gets slower.

> Of course its easy to work with entity framework, But I think the
>   performance better on stored procedure

And why would that be? The overhead of generating the query is tiny, and contrary to often repeated delusions - SQL Server uses query plan caching for everything. A SP is faster - if the compilation overhead is significant (i.e. SMALL data), or if you otherwise pull a lot of data over a network in order to send results back (processing only in database).

For anyhing else the "general" performance impact is close to zero.

OTOH it allows you to send much more tailored SQL without geting into really bad and ugly stored procedures - that either issue dynamic SQL internally, or have tons of complex conditions for optional parameters.

What to be careful with:

- IN clauses can be terrible for performance. DO not put hundreds of elements in there. IF you need that - a SP and a table variable that prepares and is joined is the better way.
- As I said - careful with paging. Someone asking for page 100 and just pressing forward is repeating a TON of processing.

And: Attitude adjustment. The time where 10 million rows where large are around 20 years ago.